# Return month and year in a Oracle database

Tags: oracle

OK, this may be a simple question but I don't know the command to do it.

I want to retrieve specific data based on a given month and year.  Assume the user wants to see all the employees that were hired in Jun 2011.  How can I write the command?

```
    SELECT  hire_date, to_char(hire_date, 'month') 
    FROM    employees 
    WHERE   to_char(hire_date,'MM') = '06';
```

This will return all the employees that were hired in the month of June. But I only want the ones hired in the year 2011. How can I put the year into the command?

Answer (score 5):

```
where to_char(hire_date, 'YYYYMM') = '201106';
```

or (more index-friendly)

```
where hire_date between 
   to_date('20110601', 'YYYYMMDD') and to_date('20110701', 'YYYYMMDD')
                                               -- or maybe '20110630'
```

Comment: between includes both endpoints, so I would recommend: where hire_date >= 
   to_date('20110601', 'YYYYMMDD') and hire_date < to_date('20110701', 'YYYYMMDD')

This way you don't have to think as much about how many days are in each month and changing your code for Feb on leap years